# Express route declaration

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 routes such as,

```
router.get("/project/:id", (req,res) => {

console.log(1);

});

router.get("/project/active", (req,res) => {

console.log(2);

})
```

Whenever I call the /project/active route, /project/:id route is getting called.

Any tips here would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wildcard route with `:id` in it is greedy and is matching everything including the `/project/active` URL.

In this route definition:

```
router.get("/project/:id", ...)
```

The `:id` part is a wildcard.  It matches ANYTHING.  So, `/project/anything` will match that, including `/project/active`.  Since routes are matched in Express in the order they are declared, your `router.get("/project/:id", ...)` route matches first and takes the request.

There are four ways around this:

1. Don't design or declare conflicting routes that might both match a particular URL.  In this particular case, you would change one of your two URLs to something unique such as `/project/id/:id` and `/project/active` or `/project/:id` and `/activeproject`.  Then, these two route handlers will never conflict.
2. Very carefully order your routes from the most specific to the least specific.  In this case, you would put `router.get("/project/active", ...)` before `router.get("/project/:id", ...)`.  That gives the more specific route a chance to match before the wildcard route gets to take the request.  But, note that this means that your `id` value can never be named `active`.
3. If your ids are uniquely identifiable and different from strings like `active` (like suppose an ID is all numbers or always contains some numbers), then you can code a regex for the ID that would only match your id values and would not match regular words like `active.
4. Code your wildcard route to individually check for things it should not match and call `next()` to continue routing to other routes.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess we need to have something like exact keyword in express/NodeJS as we have in ReactJS where the route matches the exact path.

Comment: @SreeSajai - `router.get("/project/active", ...)` is exact match.  But, `router.get("/project/:id", ...)` is wildcard match.  If you put wildcard match first, it wins.  So, if you create conflicts, you just have to order them properly.  IMO, best not to design conflicts into your URL scheme as that can also lead to namespace conflicts too (where a valid id conflicts with some other URL you defined).

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you specify a dynamic route before a specific route.

The right one should be:

```js
router.get("/project/active", (req,res) => {
  console.log(2);
});

router.get("/project/:id", (req,res) => {
  console.log(1);
});
```

In Node.js, we know something that is called a middleware stack. Basically, your requests will pass through middlewares until something gives out a response. Routers are also examples of middlewares.

In this case, your route assumes that `/active` is an `id`, as you defined `/:id` first before `/active`. Different things (should be your expected behavior) would happen if you switched the order.

References:

- [Middleware Stack](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)