# Express Router calling dynamic route instead of correct named route

Tags: javascript, express, express-router

I'm building an API on Express.js, using routes and controllers.

In my api.js file I have:

```
const app = express()    
app.use('/clients', clients)
```

And i n my router/client.js I have:

```
import ClientsController from '../controllers/clients'

clients.get('/', ClientsController.getAll)
clients.get('/getAllProspects', ClientsController.getAllProspects)
clients.get('/:id', ClientsController.getClientData)
```

When I put the `clients.get('/:id', ClientsController.getClientData)` in the line before `clients.get('/getAllProspects', ClientsController.getAllProspects)` and try to call the `clients/getAllProspects` in Postman, I get the `/:id` result instead.

Am I doing something wrong? Can anyone clarify on this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A [fully explained answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836587/express-route-declaration/68838617#68838617) in an answer from earlier in the day.  Wildcard routes match  ANYTHING so you have to put them last if you are creating conflicting routes.  I can't mark this a duplicate of that one because that earlier answer has not yet been accepted, but this is exactly the same question.

Comment: @jfriend00 I searched the site for a question like my own, never found that one. Thanks for the link, this answer my question.

Comment: No problem.  It is often hard to know what to search for and can depend upon which specific words were used in similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

`clients.get('/:id', ClientsController.getClientData)` will match `'/getAllProspects'`, so the id will be `getAllProspects` , so I suggest you change

```
clients.get('/:id', ClientsController.getClientData)
```

to

```
clients.get('/id/:id', ClientsController.getClientData)
```